# Azure Resources API doesn't give me all fields

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I can't make the Azure Resources API return the full list of fields as it promises to do. The address of the API:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list

I'm calling:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resources?api-version=2019-10-01&%24filter=resourceType%20eq%20'Microsoft.Compute%2FvirtualMachines'
```

which gives me the list in a form:

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "id": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/xxx-x-xxx-xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxx-x-xxx-xxxxx",
      "name": "xxx-x-xxx-xxxxx",
      "location": "xxxxxxx",
      "zones": [
        "1"
      ],
      "plan": {
        "name": "xxxxxxx",
        "product": "xxxxxxx",
        "publisher": "xxxxxxx"
      },
      "tags": {
        "MYID": "xxxxxxx"
      }
    }
```

What I miss is information about e.g. **VM size** (inside SKU).

I tried adding `$expand` parameter, but it only works for parameters which have

> This is only present if requested via the $expand query parameter.

in their description. Examples are: `createdTime` and `changedTime`.

I understand that the rest of the parameters should always be returned. But they are not.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The list-resources API call doesn't return the full list of fields. What you can do is perform a GET on each resource in turn, or if you're using AzureRMR, call `sync_fields()` for each resource object returned by `list_resources()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default the REST API specification / schema of [Resources - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) doesn't capture VMsize / SKU. You may leverage [Virtual Machines - List All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall) which provides VMsize / SKU in the output format like shown below.

```
{
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "location": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "tags": {
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      },
      "properties": {
        "vmId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```